# How would I git merge two of the same projects that have an original ancestor but diverged?

Tags: git, merge, git-branch, git-merge, git-checkout

I have a project (effectively a folder with a bunch of files).

Say I have a main release that is now on version 5.2.

Back when it was on version 3.0, I duplicated the folder and began working on a separate set of features. Like a poor version of git branch.

Since then obviously the main version is on 5.2 and now I want to merge this branched off version back into the main version, effectively into a 6.0 version.

How would I best do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I duplicated the folder

That's `git clone` with some minor cleanup and convenience renaming omitted.  The important thing is, the two repos are built on common history.

In your main-release repo the command sequence would be

```
git remote add sideproject /path/to/sideproject
git fetch sideproject
```

and now you've got all the history in your main repo, you can `git merge sideproject/master` or whatever branch name you're using there.